# TypeScript object cast to interface should not compile?

Tags: typescript

I can't understand why this TypeScript code should compile (TypeScript 2.8.3 all strict checks on)

I've cast an object to type IUser and included a property which doesn't exist "bob"

I've read the documentation on excess checks - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks

But it still doesn't make sense that this should compile - given I'm casting it.

The ultimate question is: How can I actually get proper typing on this object - such that casting it to an object with non-interface members (a possibly/likely typo) should fail to compile.

```
interface IUser {
    name: string
}

const func = (user: IUser) => {
    alert(user)
}

func(<IUser> {
    name: "bob",
    bob: true
} as IUser)
```

Comment: Why do you need the type assertion (the 'cast') to fail? If you had a function that accepted an `IUser` and you passed `{ name: "bob", bob: true }`, it would fail.

Comment: @cartant I've updated the code so the function receives object type IUser, it still compiles

Comment: Without the type assertions, it will fail. With the type assertions, you are circumventing the excess property checks.

Comment: Right, I'm not forcing it to by abide to IUser, but inadvertently forcing it to compile by telling the compiler "don't worry it is IUser"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extra properties check is done only when assigning object literal to a variable or function parameter. Adding any kind of cast disables the check, because the value actually is assignable to the type. This feature is called [Strict **object literal** assignment checking](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#strict-object-literal-assignment-checking):

> It is an error to specify properties in an object literal that were
>   not specified on the target type, when assigned to a variable or
>   passed for a parameter of a non-empty target type.

Example where the an extra property gives an error:

```
interface IUser {
  name: string
}

const anotherFunc = function (u: IUser) {
    // whatever
}

const func = function() {
    anotherFunc({
        name: "bob",
        bob: true
    })
}

// Argument of type '{ name: string; bob: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IUser'.
//   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bob' does not exist in type 'IUser'.
```

Comment: Thanks, and here I was thinking that adding the type was making the code clearer, but I was actually making it looser

Comment: Type casts, also called type assertions, are [a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). In TypeScript, they are useful only when compiler can't figure out types on its own, and could be harmful otherwise.